# VB Script to call POST API with form data and file upload

Tags: post, vbscript

I am working on a vb script which has to call a POST API to upload a file from local along with input data (input params). The VB script is invoked from a batch file.

Here is my vb script:

```
`Dim APIobjRequest
Dim APIstrUrl 
Dim APIblnAsync 
Dim APIstrResponse 

Dim APILabel 
Dim APIscriptControl
Set APIscriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
APIscriptControl.Language = "JScript"
Dim JSON 
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")

Set fso=createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
strPath="C:\Users\T4G.csv"
sBoundary = "-ooo-"
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFS.FileExists(strPath) Then
    Set objFlagFile = objFS.Getfile(strPath)
End IF


Set APIobjRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
APISstrUrl = "https://XXX/uploadFile"
APIblnAsync = False
authKey = "XXX"
formData = "filename=objFlagFile&test1=testInput1&test2=testInput2&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&resource=XXX"
'formParams = "filename=objFlagFile&test1=testInput1&test2=testInput2&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&resource=XXX"

With APIobjRequest
    .Open "POST", APISstrUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + sBoundary
    .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
    .Send (formData)
    
    If APIobjRequest.Status = 200 Then
    'msgbox "RESPONSE : " & http.responseXML.xml
    msgbox "RESPONSE : " & APIobjRequest.responseText
    responseText=APIobjRequest.responseText
    WScript.Echo "+++++++++"& responseText
    else
    WScript.Echo "---------"& APIobjRequest.status
    msgbox "ERRCODE : " & APIobjRequest.status      
    End If
End With`
```

When I run the script I am getting type mismatch syntax error.

I am not exactly sure on how to write VB script for file upload along with passing input as form params/form data.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: It is a Visual Basic script

Comment: Form data suggests you are HTML form posting to this page to initiate the API call, which probably means this is Classic ASP which you haven't tagged. Although, how the ScriptControl fits into that I have no idea.

Comment: We don't have any front end for this requirement. A batch file invokes the VB Script which should call the POST API to upload a file from local along with input data (input params).

Comment: That is useful information to include in the question, so we better understand the context of the problem. It's simple to update a question just [edit] like you would a wiki.

Comment: Included the details to my question.